# How to reduce the Windows 7 menu expansion delay?

Tags: windows-7

Ok, so you hover over the items pinned to the Win 7 menu, and wait all month for it to pop out the sub menu containing recent items opened with the selected app.

Is there a registry hack to speed this up?  I want the sub menus quicker.

Same applies to the delay before things Control Panel and Administrative Tools pop out their sub menus too.

It just takes too long, so how to reduce that delay?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Windows 7 Forums:

> How to Speed up the Menu Show Delay Time in Windows 7
>
> http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/731-menu-show-delay-time.html

1. Open the Start Menu, then type regedit in the search boxand press Enter. (See screenshot below):
   [image]
2. In regedit, navigate to the location below.(See screenshot below)

   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\desktop`
3. In the right pane, right click on MenuShowDelay and click on Modify.

   [image]
4. Type in a number between 0 to 4000 (400 is default, I use 1) for how many milliseconds you want the Menu to wait before it opens. (See screenshot below)
   NOTE: The lower the number, the faster the response time. If you use an entry of 0, there is no menu display delay. However it is not recommended to use 0 though since the menus may be hard to navigate through at that speed.

   [image]
5. Click on OK to apply.
6. Close regedit.
7. Log off and log on, or restart the computer to apply the changes.

Answer (score 3):

As I change this setting on each computer I use, here is was a quick way to do it (same registry key as the one pointed out in studiohack's answer):

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>  +  <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Write in the input box `REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\desktop" -v MenuShowDelay -d 0 -t REG_SZ -f`
3. Press  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Alternatively, you can create a .reg file (e.g. `fixmenu.reg`) with the following content, and execute it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\desktop]
"MenuShowDelay"="0"
```

As usual, for the change to be effective restart the Windows session (by log off/in, or rebooting the OS)

Answer (score 0):

As a brief update, this is still valid for Windows 10. See [this](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/14428-change-menu-show-delay-time-windows-10-a.html).